# Taking forever to connect to the Windows Phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

For some reason in the last month or so it's taking FOREVER to connect to my Windows Phone 7 emulator.  This used to take around 15-30 seconds but now it takes around 3 minutes.  When I press F5 in VS 2010 it just seems to stop on the message "Connecting to Windows Phone 7 Emulator...".  But i can see the emulator started and ready in about 10 seconds.  I'm on the same machine, same solution, same everything.

Is just me or has this started happening to everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using WPConnect.exe  instead and see if there are any changes:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2010/10/26/quick-tip-using-the-wp-connect-utility-instead-of-zune-client-windows-phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not happening here.

Could your project be growing in size? Try a blank project.

What people have had a problem with is USB ports failing. Try also moving to a USB port on the back of your PC, and one that you know performs ok.